# Computation of an integral involving summation over factorials.

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, factorial

For the computation of an expected value, with $m>i$ and $m,i\in\mathbb{N}$, I am trying to show that

$$
\int_0^1 x\cdot m\binom{m-1}{i-1}x^{i-1}(1-x)^{m-i}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{i}{m+1}.
$$

However, I am apparently lacking some Binomial/Gamma/Factorial identities in order to simplify the sum that arises:

\begin{alignat*}{3}
&\int_0^1 x\cdot m\binom{m-1}{i-1}x^{i-1}(1-x)^{m-i}\mathrm{d}x\\
=&\frac{m!}{(i-1)!(m-i)!}\int_0^1 x^i \sum_{k=0}^{m-i}\binom{m-i}{k}x^k\mathrm{d}x\\
=&\frac{m!}{(i-1)!(m-i)!}\int_0^1 (m-i)!\sum_{k=0}^{m-i}\frac{1}{k!(m-i-k)!}x^{i+k}\mathrm{d}x\\
=&\frac{m!}{(i-1)!}\sum_{k=0}^{m-i}\frac{1}{k!(m-i-k)!(i+k+1)}\\
=&\ldots
\end{alignat*}

where I start being lost. I am fine using Gamma/Beta/Pochhammer notation but could not come up with identities that allowed be to simplify the form I am stuck with. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hint: the integral is a beta function

Comment: Aaaah, of course! That should do it! Thank you! If you want to turn this into an answer, I could accept it straight away.

Comment: i'm too busy right now...sorry. but glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that
$$\int_0^1 x\cdot m\binom{m-1}{i-1}x^{i-1}(1-x)^{m-i}\mathrm{d}x=
i\binom{m}{i}\int_0^1 x^{i}(1-x)^{m-i}\mathrm{d}x=i\binom{m}{i}B(i+1,m-i+1)=\frac{i}{m+1}
$$
where we used the definition of [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and the following known property: for any positive integers $x$ and $y$ then
$$B(x,y)=\frac{(x-1)!(y-1)!}{(x+y-1)!}.$$